# Encode MP3 file to base64 string in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a app that use cordova-plugin-media to record and audio file, and now I want to encode this file to base64 string, for now I can locate the file but when I try to encode it I get this :

"{"$$state":{"status":0}}"

Here is my code

```
audio.stopRecord();
audio.play();
if(device.platform == "iOS")
{
    var path = cordova.file.tempDirectory;
}
else if(device.platform == "Android")
{
    var path = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory;
}

var filename = name + extension;
var filepath = path + filename;


console.log(filepath);
console.log(JSON.stringify($cordovaFile.readAsDataURL(path, filename)));
```

file path : `file:///storage/emulated/0/tPUhcxUKhmLUrWK3Qkqhc69OxeEIWyYrhEB0he9OwM0ffmjY2OUh3TLbFTsApdpIpjxyuC2wouyCs6m7uvdOCHCMiw9mbLMGYM25.mp3`

Can any one help me with this??

Thanks

Comment: Did you run a debugger on the code? Does your call to `atob` get the data you expect it to get?

Comment: i think that the problem , i need to get base64 string of the audio file , and i'm not sure how i can do it .

Comment: OK. Can you reduce your question to *just that*? A "how do I convert format A to format B?" is a lot more concrete than "why doesn't my app work?". Concrete questions like that (when they include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) attract more, better answers and upvotes.

Comment: question edited , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**readAsDataURL** needs a file object, it won't work with a string path.

Give the following code a try, working on iOS and Android

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function(fileEntry) {fileEntry.file(function (file) {
 var reader = new FileReader();

 reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    var base64String = evt.target.result;
 };

 reader.readAsDataURL(file);

});}, function(e){console.log("error:" + JSON.stringify(e));});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but what path format i should give when using ios devices ??

Comment: var path = cordova.file.tempDirectory + "music.wav"; this works for me

Comment: thanks for your reply , BTW do you have any idea about this error : http://stackoverflow.com/q/39643801/1845649

Comment: thanks for your reply , but i have the error on IOS not android