# ionic Cordova Failed recording audio on IOS using Media plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i'm working on an ionic App and i need to record audio files , so i used the cordova-plugin-media , it worked fine for android but when i tried it on ios i get this error :

> {"message":"Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder","code":1}

here is my code :

```
var extension = '.wav';
var name = 'filename';
var audio = null;
var filepath;

$scope.startRecording = function() {
  name = Utils.generateFilename();
  if(device.platform == "iOS")
  {
     //var path = "documents://";
     //var path = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
     //var path = cordova.file.cacheDirectory;
     var path = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
     path = path.replace("file:///", "cdvfile://");

  }
  else if(device.platform == "Android")
  {
    var path = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory;
  }
  var filename = name + extension;
  filepath = path + filename;
  audio = new Media(filepath, function(e){console.log(e, "success Media");},function(e){console.log(e, "error");});
    audio.startRecord();

  };

  $scope.sendAudioMsg = function() {
     audio.stopRecord();
     audio.release();
  };
```

when i console log the path i get this :

> cdvfile://var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F47A76AD-E776-469F-8EFA-85B0A0F14754/Library/NoCloud/dJzSapEU6k16hV7EGrD06L29NjZcOCVzHCUTrcjEDiTCF7uUNGmCHchEcwfGls3V88p85ij0NUkv0KVagevbgh3lwWsEfmAO8uNq.wav

can any one help me??

Comment: I encoutered the same problem. Did you resolve this?

Comment: if you found solution plz post it

Comment: @Ionut please see my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try following for Android.

```
var path = "Android/data/"+YOUR_APP_ID+"/files/"+FILENAME+".wav";

var myMedia = new Media(path, success, error);
myMedia.startRecord();
```

To access file after you are done with recording

```
var path = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+"files/"+FILENAME+".wav";
var myMedia1 = new Media(path, success, error);
myMedia1.play();
```

YOUR_APP_ID would be com.test.app

iOS, see following

```
var fileName = "myrec.wav";
var myMedia = new Media(path, success, error);
myMedia.startRecord();
```

To access file

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, 0, function (fileSystem){
            fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, null, function (fileEntry){
                fileEntry.file(function OnFileEntry(file){
                    // file is actual recorded file, get the path and play or get base64 string
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                        evt.target.result; // this is base64 string
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }, error);
            }, error);
        }, error);
```

Comment: i don't have any problem with android. but i have this error on IOS as i mentioned it on the title , thanks

Comment: "Failed to start recording using AVAudioRecorder", even if i use .wav on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is for IOS only

I was having the same error message when trying to use Media for recording and setting the location of recorded file to any of below combinations

```
var pathFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
pathFile = 'documents://';
pathFile = cordova.file.documentsDirectory;
```

Then i realized that passing only file name will save the file in Temp directory (cordova.file.tempDirectory) so i end up getting the recording to work on IOS using this way (I am posting the full code and my only note that i was using the media plugin with compression instead of the normal media plugin)

```
    // Save the recorded fileName
    var fileName = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1) + ".m4a";

    if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        var pathFile = '';
    } else {
        var pathFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
    }

    src = pathFile + fileName;

    if (mediaRec == null) {
        mediaRec = new Media(src,
            // success callback
            function () {
                console.log("recordCompressedAudio():Audio Success");
            },

            // error callback
            function (err) {
                console.log("recordCompressedAudio():Audio Error: " + err.code);
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    // Record MPEG compressed audio, single channel at 16kHz
    var options = {
        SampleRate: 16000,
        NumberOfChannels: 1
    }

    mediaRec.startRecordWithCompression(options);

    console.log("Recording Started");
    console.log(mediaRec);
}
```

Then i end up resolving the location for recorded file using the Temp directory by passing "cordova.file.tempDirectory + src" to resolveLocalFileSystemURL

```
    console.log("Recording Stopped");
    console.log(mediaRec);
    mediaRec.stopRecord();
    mediaRec.release();

    resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        cordova.file.tempDirectory + src,
        function (entry) {
            console.log('cdvfile URI: ');
            console.log(entry);
            player.src = entry.toURL();
            console.log("Saved file location :" + src.toInternalURL());
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('about to resolve this files errors');
            console.log(error);
        });
```

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer see my answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, where i was using native recording GUI

**IOS**

```
cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "tmp/OSAudioRecordings/" + file_name;
```

**ANDROID**

```
cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "files/AudioRecords/" + file_name;
```